# WDS MDT - Enable specific task sequence in a config file

Tags: deployment, wds

I'm trying to enable a win10 Client install- task sequence on different deploy$ shares.
Instead of copying the whole new updated deploy share onto all the servers, can't I just edit a line in some config file ? 
The boot images for win10 were spread on all deploy shares beforehand but it was just not 'enabled' in Deployment workbench. 'see picture'
[Deployment Workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70k5v.png)

Comment: I would recommend rewording your question. It was kinda hard to interpret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Well yes you can!

Here is the code to specifically select the task sequence that you want (in the future you might want to be more clear with the wording of your question):

`Tasksequenceid=TaskSequenceIDhere`

You can put that setting in your `bootstrap.ini` or in your `customsettings.ini`. If you put in your `bootstrap.ini` file then you will need to regenerate your boot images.

---

## Extra extra read all about it!!!

You can extend this functionality to reduce the ammount of boot images that you need by combining this code with other code like so:

```
[Settings]
Priority=Architecture, TaskSequenceID, Default

[x86]
Tasksequenceid=W7UX86

[x64]
Tasksequenceid=W7UX64

[W7UX86]
SkipRoles=YES
SkipSummary=YES
SkipAdminPassword=YES
SkipApplications=YES
SkipDomainMembership=YES
SkipComputerName=YES
etc...
```

Another tip is that you can make a boot image per task sequence if you put this setting in the `bootstrap.ini`file:

After regenerating the boot file, move them/it to a new location and set the new setting(s) then regenerate the image(s) again. There you go, two images that both execute different task sequences from the same deployment share when booted!

Enjoy!